# App Engine Query Users

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

I have the User model in my datastore which contains some attributes:

[image]

I need to query all users filtering by the `company` attribute.

So, as I would normally do, I do this:

```
from webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models import User

employees = User.query().filter(User.company == self.company_name).fetch()
```

This gives me:

> AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'company'

And when I do:

```
employees = User.query().filter().fetch()
```

It gives me no error and shows the list with all the Users.

How do I query by field? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit misdirected. You ask how to query by field, which you are already doing with correct syntax. The problem, as Jeff O'Neill noted, is your `User` model does not have that `company` field, so your query-by-field attempt results in an error. ([Here is some ndb documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entities) that you should definitely peruse and bookmark if you haven't already.) There are three ways to remedy your missing-field problem:

1. Subclass the `User` model, as Jeff shows in his answer. This is quick and simple, and may be the best solution for what you want.
2. Create your own User model, completely separate from the webapp2 one. This is probably overkill for what you want, just judging from your question, because you would have to write most of your own authentication code that the webapp2 user already handles for you.
3. Create a new model that contains extra user information, and has a key property containing the corresponding user's key. That would look like this:

   ```
   class UserProfile(ndb.Expando):
       user_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='User', required=True)
       company = ndb.StringProperty()
       # other possibilities: profile pic? address? etc.
   ```

   with queries like this:

   ```
   from models.user_profile import UserProfile
   from webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models import User
   from google.appengine.ext import ndb

   # get the employee keys
   employee_keys = UserProfile.query(UserProfile.company == company_name).fetch(keys_only=True)

   # get the actual user objects
   employees = ndb.get_multi(employee_keys)
   ```

   What this solution does is it separates your User model that you use for authentication (webapp2's User) from the model that holds extra user information (UserProfile). If you want to store profile pictures or other relatively large amounts of data for each user, you may find this solution works best for you.

Note: you can put your filter criteria in the `.query()` parentheses to simplify things (I find I rarely use the `.filter()` method):

```
# long way
employees = User.query().filter(User.company == self.company_name).fetch()

# shorter way
employees = User.query(User.company == self.company_name).fetch()
```

Answer (score 1):

You've imported a `User` class defined by webapp2.  This `User` class does not have an attribute called `company` so that is why you are getting the error from `User.company`.

You probably want to do create your own `User` model by subclassing the one provided by webapp2:

```
from webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models import User as Webapp2_User

class User(Webapp2_User):
    company = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Then your query should work.

One caveat, I've never used `webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models` so I don't know what that is exactly.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that's what I would do in case I didn't succeed with a simpler approach. Simpler in terms of reimplementation effort.